# Fetch JSON data with dashes or hyphens in React

Tags: json, reactjs, fetch

Anyone knows how to solve this problem with react? I need to fetch this data:

```
<source src={items.preview-hq-mp3.} type="audio/mpeg"></source>
```

but give error because dashes...[error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cmKNo.png)

Answer (score 1):

## How to Fetch an object with special characters in the key

You can reference a key with a string and square brackets. This is useful for when you need to get a srance file name or json as part of an object.

In your case I'm not sure if the `.` at the end is a typo? but this should work either way, so long as it matches the key properly.

```
<source src={items["preview-hq-mp3."]} type="audio/mpeg"></source>
```

A bonus use case for this is when you have a variable key name.

```
const key = "myKey";

const obj = {[key]: 'my value'} // prints out {myKey: 'my value'}
```